# jQuery mouseout always triggered

Tags: jquery, menu, mouseover

I have a vertical menubar and the active menu item has a 1px line underneath it. When hover another menu item, the line is slide to under the hovered item. When mouse over the menu, the line should slide back to the active menu item. The problem is, that the mouseout event always triggered, even when cursor only moves over the menu items. In this case, every time when hovers an item, the line slides under it, and when hover the menu item next to it, the line slides to the active menu item (because mouseout triggered) and slides from active item to the hovered.

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>    
        <li class="active"><a href="#">menu1</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header { height: 21px; }
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 20px; }
ul li { display: inline-block; float: left; height: 20px; }
ul li a { padding: 0px 15px; line-height: 20px; }
.line { height: 1px; background-color: red; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Select active item
    var currentWidth = $(".header ul li.active").css('width');
    var marginLeft = 0;
    $.each($(".header ul li"), function(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) return false;
        else marginLeft += parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
    });
    $(".header .line").css({ 'width': currentWidth, 'margin-left': marginLeft + 'px' });

    // Hover item
    $(".header ul li").hover(function() {
        var thisPos = $(".header ul li").index($(this));
        var thisWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
        marginLeft = 0;
        $.each($(".header ul li"), function(){
          if ( $(this).is($(".header ul li:eq(" + thisPos + ")")) ) return false;
          else marginLeft += parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
        });
        $(".header .line").animate({ 'width': thisWidth, 'margin-left': marginLeft }, 200);
    }, function(){
        // This one works wrong !!!
        var currentWidth = $(".header ul li.active").css('width');
        var marginLeft = 0;
        $.each($(".header ul li"), function(){
          if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) return false;
          else marginLeft += parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
        });
        $(".header .line").animate({ 'width': currentWidth, 'margin-left': marginLeft }, 200);
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4U8V6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mouseleave of the `li` elements, handle mouseleave from the `ul` element

```
// Hover item
$(".header ul li").mouseenter(function () {
    var thisPos = $(".header ul li").index($(this));
    var thisWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
    marginLeft = 0;
    $.each($(".header ul li"), function () {
        if ($(this).is($(".header ul li:eq(" + thisPos + ")"))) return false;
        else marginLeft += parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
    });
    $(".header .line").animate({
        'width': thisWidth,
            'margin-left': marginLeft
    }, 200);
});

$('.header ul').mouseleave(function () {
    // This one works wrong !!!
    var currentWidth = $(".header ul li.active").css('width');
    var marginLeft = 0;
    $.each($(".header ul li"), function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
        else marginLeft += parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
    });
    $(".header .line").animate({
        'width': currentWidth,
            'margin-left': marginLeft
    }, 200);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lp7Cy/)

---

Another way is a timer based solution like

```
var $ul = $('.header ul')
// Hover item
$ul.find$("li").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout($ul.data('mouseleave'));

    var thisPos = $(".header ul li").index($(this));
    var thisWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
    marginLeft = 0;
    $.each($(".header ul li"), function () {
        if ($(this).is($(".header ul li:eq(" + thisPos + ")"))) return false;
        else marginLeft += parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
    });
    $(".header .line").animate({
        'width': thisWidth,
            'margin-left': marginLeft
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        var currentWidth = $(".header ul li.active").css('width');
        var marginLeft = 0;
        $.each($(".header ul li"), function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
            else marginLeft += parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px', ''));
        });
        $(".header .line").animate({
            'width': currentWidth,
                'margin-left': marginLeft
        }, 200);
    }, 100);
    $ul.data('mouseleave', timer)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LfGfM/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first one will work fine. Ps. I've just heard about mouseleave and mouseenter.